# Exporting text from from multiple Excel files to a single comma delimited file

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I need to export data from Excel to a comma delimited file. I am using a button that runs a macro that creates the text file in a location I specify and exports values.

But, I want to copy this Excel with the same macro, and add different values. When I run the macro in the copied Excel file I want the same text delimited file to add these values under the previous set of values, not overwrite the values from the first Excel file.

How is this possible? I want to use the same text file each time.

Answer (score 3):

Append using following routine:

```
Sub writeCSV(ByVal thisRange As Range, ByVal filePath As String, _
             Optional ByVal fileAppend As Boolean = False)
    Dim cLoop As Long, rLoop As Long
    Dim ff As Long, strRow As String

    ff = FreeFile
    If fileAppend Then
        Open filePath For Append As #ff
    Else
        Open filePath For Output As #ff
    End If

    For rLoop = 1 To thisRange.Rows.Count
        strRow = ""
        For cLoop = 1 To thisRange.Columns.Count
            If cLoop > 1 Then strRow = strRow & ","
            strRow = strRow & thisRange.Cells(rLoop, cLoop).Value
        Next 'cLoop
        Print #ff, strRow
    Next 'rLoop

    Close #ff
End Sub
```

Example usage

```
writeCSV sheet1, "c:\test.txt", true
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to do it by using a `StreamWriter`. The `AppendText` function of the `FileInfo` class returns one that is configured for appending text to an existing file.

I write my example as pseudo code, as I don't know how you are retrieving the information from Excel. The File handling part, however, is complete:

```
Dim file As New FileInfo("C:\myOuputFile.csv")
Using writer = file.AppendText()
    While isRowAvailable
        writer.WriteLine("Write next row")
    End While
End Using
```

The `Using` statement automatically closes the file at the end.